# How to download video url

Tags: swift, download

This is the response -:
[image]i want to download this url -:

```
https://cdn2me.net/L/eNoBqABX%252F5EN1R2oop8oi1a7whfN%252BmD7GlXymaqErLW%252BZOOGbn1oLUgtRB4Uai2qRmsPUL2KHzdi9raOcTUQmkUfiDMyw7roq7CORnxqngywtE9trCLn%252FJS9l5XAILjNhMXzVOlbB2HFUlHe25G2XXzMu522YyFjIjqjVe39f2g%252FAsVifP5tpkQ0ExZnscq9Af4cY5557XvfsTmeaPBXlEXbN9EdAIlc%252FP%252BS%252FsTZJIBEVW8%253D
```

i am writing this code -:

```
 let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
    Alamofire.download(
        url,
        method: .get,
        parameters: nil,
        encoding: URLEncoding.default,
        headers: nil,
        to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            let percentage = Float(progress.fractionCompleted) * 100
            print("Music Percentage\(percentage)")
            CallbackListener.resumeCallbackHelper.OnResume(status: percentage)
        }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
            
            print("DefaultDownloadResponse\(fetchPathinDirectory(filepath:url.lastPathComponent))")
            let imageURL = fetchPathinDirectory(filepath:DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL!.lastPathComponent)
            completion(imageURL)

        })
```

this url is not downloading.but other url downloading is working fine with this code.

Comment: `DefaultDownloadResponse`: Is there any error there?

Comment: Please check i update my question @Larme